# Why is firebug auto-inserting </p>?

Tags: html, firefox, firebug

I am using "Edit Html" in firebug and inserting the following bit of code:

```
  <div title="show-details">
    X
    <p class="quick-details">
      <p title="about-player">
        <p title="name">Drew Brees #9</p>
        <p title="position">Quarterback</p>
        <p title="team">The Saints</p>
      </p>
    </p>
  </div>
```

However, when I move off of edit html mode, what is actually IN the DOM is this:

```
<div title="show-details">
    X
    <p class="quick-details">
      </p><p title="about-player">
    </p><p title="name">Drew Brees #9</p>
        <p title="position">Quarterback</p>
        <p title="team">The Saints</p>
      <p></p>
    <p></p>
  </div>
```

Am I missing something about how the `p` element works? The MDC says the content can be any flow element. Where are those `</p>`s coming from? Is it firefox? firebug?

**Edit before I accept the answer:** So apparently `<p>` cannot nest within `<p>`, does that mean that [the MDC is wrong](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/p#Usage_context) or that I am somehow misinterpreting it?

Comment: Other elements that can be used in the <p> tags include: spans, b, anchors, small, strong and stuff like that.

Comment: I've updated my answer to reflect your edit.

Comment: The MDC page was wrong.  I've fixed it.  The spec at http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-p-element is pretty clear that only phrasing content is allowed as a child of `<p>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `p` element isn't allowed inside another `p` element, and its end tag is optional, Firebug (or rather, the underlying HTML/SGML parser) inserts an end tag where it (correctly) guesses there should be one.

**Edit:** The [HTML 4.01 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.3.1) is very clear on this; you cannot nest `p` elements (and in that respect, the MDC is incorrect). <del>The [HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-p-element), however, is very unclear on the subject (I have submitted feedback on the issue)</del> The HTML5 spec is crystal clear on the subject, I'm just reading it wrong, and common sense as well as typographic effect dictates that a paragraph of text (which the `p` element represents) cannot contain a second paragraph of text.

Comment: Really? According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/p#Usage_context p is one of the flow content elements and can accept any flow content element and be within any element that accepts flow content

Comment: @George: Well, according to [the HTML 4.01 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.3.1) (and HTML5 as well), "*The P element represents a paragraph. It cannot contain block-level elements (including P itself)*."

Answer (score 7):

It is [incorrect to nest](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.3.1) `<p>` elements.

Firefox parses the HTML to get a DOM tree. The DOM tree is always [well-formed](http://webtips.dan.info/nesting.html) even if the source code isn't. This representation might also present whitespace and escape codes differently.

Firebug primarily works with the DOM representation. This

- is simpler,
- is less likely to suffer from discrepencies of interpretation,
- and makes it possible to diagnose poorly-written HTML.

Firebug will refer back to the source only for things like script debugging.

Answer (score 3):

Probably happening because `<p>` are `block-level` elements and cannot contain other `block-level` elements.

Firebug is compensating and auto-correcting.

Answer (score 3):

from w3 documentation

> The P element represents a paragraph. It cannot contain block-level
>   elements (including P itself).

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.3.1

Answer (score -1):

```
<div title="show-details">
  X
  <div class="quick-details">
    <div title="about-player">
      <p title="name">Drew Brees #9</p>
      <p title="position">Quarterback</p>
      <p title="team">The Saints</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It makes the corrections needed to prevent the issue presented so it actually does.

Comment: I disagree. The question is "Where are those </p>s coming from? Is it firefox? firebug?", not "How can I write correct code?". While these questions are related and can be dealt with at the same time, you should at least answer the explicit question.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sorry Tyler, I know that `<div>` would work, I was confused by why `<p>` does not

Comment: @You, I don't think my answer deserves a down-vote. No reason to hurt those that are trying to be constructive. A down-vote would be for an answer that is completely wrong or irrelevant.